# Magento 2: how to use sql queries on controller?

Tags: magento2, sql

Please, how we can use sql queries on controller? i am using Magento 2 and this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;


class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: 'sql queries' - means? 'select * from ....' this type flat query?

Comment: all sql queries

Comment: You should go with ResourceModel.

Comment: follow this link  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112057/form-cretation-for-custom-tab-in-customer-dashboard-mageto-2  I hope this is useful for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ResourceConnection Method if you wish to use sql queries in Controller.

```
  $resource = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
  $connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
  $values = $connection->fetchAll('select * from `table` ');
```

Comment: I disagree for two reasons: one should never use the object manager directly and every SQL queries must always be executed from the resource models that's their purpose

Answer (score 4):

You should not do it in controller. ResourceModel Layer is resposible for data persistence